# Merge thread coroutine output in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, coroutine

If I have a multiple threads, each of which has a cppcoro::generator, is there a straghtforward construct that will merge them together (in the main thread) to a single generator (preferably FIFO)? I'm not sure how to do it in a non-hacky way, especially without wasting cycles on the main thread.

(In my case, each generator will take much more time than the main thread, so having main block each thread while it processes is fine)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I would simply have each generator-class place its results onto a thread-safe queue of your own choosing.  The main thread then simply reads from that queue.  Alternatively, a separate thread could be that "consumer" while the main thread is just the "queen bee."

Of course the results would be returned in an unpredictable sequence.